# MSTest error - MySQLConnection aborts connection after upgrading to Connector 6.6.6

Tags: mysql, mstest, mysql-connector

My database is MySQL 5.5.34 and I'd been using the MySQL Connector.NET version 6.5.4.
After uninstalling the 6.5.4 and installing version 6.6.6, I'm having issues with the connection aborting.  The relevant code, which looks essentially like the following worked fine prior to the upgrade.

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=7654;uid=matt;pwd=password");
connection.Open();  // this results in the exception
```

**This works fine** when I do this in a simple console application but **does not** work in my MS Test

The Exception I get is:

**MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'matt' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with mesage: Reading from the stream has failed"**

Drilling down into the exception, the Inner Exception is **"Unable to read data from the transport connection:  An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."**

I've tried with both VS 2010 and VS 2013.  Same error for both.

Ideas?

Comment: Perhaps it's SSL related?

Comment: I am getting this same problem, intermittently on code that has been working fine. Anyone got any ideas??